# Rolling two dice and picking the higest

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So a common mechanic in many dice games such as Warhammer or Dungeons and Dragons is that to provide and advantage on a dice roll you roll twice and pick the highest result.  I'm curious from a combinatorics perspective how this works?  It obviously makes intuitive sense like if you roll twice you get two chances to pass a test but is it possible to quantify this a little better?  Like if I am testing on a d20 (a 20 sided die for those who don't know) and I need to roll over a 10 how much does rolling twice actually increase my chances of success?

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability of success in a single trial.  Let $q=1-p$ be the probability of failure in a single trial.  At least one success out of two attempts would be $1-q^2$.  At least one success out of $n$ trials would be $1-q^n$, and so on.  For your specific example, rolling a $10$ or better occurs with probability $0.5$ in a single roll and getting at least one $10$ or better would be $0.75$ in two rolls, $0.875$ in three rolls, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than thinking of the chance of success, think of the chance of failure.  If you take the best roll out of a sequence of multiple rolls, and the outcome of each roll is independent of the outcome of all previous rolls, then the only way to fail is if *each* roll is a failure.  If any given roll has probability $q$ of failure, then the probability that every roll fails is $q^n$, where $n$ is the number of rolls performed.  If $0 < q < 1$, then $q^n < q$ for $n > 1$.

So for instance, if you have to roll at least a $10$ on a $20$-sided die, then the probability of success on a single roll is $10/20 = 1/2$, hence the probability of failure is $q = 1/2$.  If you get to take the maximum of $n = 2$ rolls, then that means the chance of failing both rolls is $q^2 = 1/4 < 1/2$.  If you get to roll $10$ times, then the chance of failing all of your rolls is $q^{10} = 1/1024$.  Again, this works because by taking the maximum value rolled, you are basically saying that *every* roll has to fail in order for you to fail overall.

Answer (score 1):

Given two rolls of a $20$ sided dice, let $P(x)$ be the probability distribution of the maximum of the two rolls. Note that $P(x\geq y)$ for a chosen $y$ is $1-P(D_{20}<y)^2=1-\frac{y-1}{20}^2$. And, $P(x=y)=P(x\geq y)-P(x\geq y+1)$.